# Ballerina jdbc DB Client throws error when select query returns empty result

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a function to read the `Notifiers` table in my db and check if there is a user by a userId. If the user is there, I return that user's last seen time, if the user is not present, I write a new entry to the db. The code is as follows:

```
isolated function getNotifier(string user_name) returns time:Utc|error {
    anydata result = check dbClient->queryRow(
        SELECT * FROM Notifier WHERE user_name = ${user_name}
    );
    if result is Notifier {
        io:println(result.last_seen);
        return result.last_seen;
    } else if result is sql:NoRowsError {
           time:Utc lastseen = time:utcNow();
           _ = check dbClient->execute(
                INSERT INTO Notifier (user_name, last_seen)
                VALUES (${user_name}, ${time:utcNow()});
              );
           return last_seen;

     } else {
        return error("Unable to obtain notifier");
     }
}
```

However, it seems that the program does not reach the if block at all and returns an error from the first result. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`check`](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/check-expression/) as you've done with the select query, if the expression with which `check` is used evaluates to an error, it would cause the function execution to stop immediately and return the error value from the function.

`sql:NoRowsError` is an error value. Therefore, if the query returns `sql:NoRowsError` (or any other error value), the function execution won't go past the first statement.

Also see [`check` semantics](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/check-semantics/).